# Open a modal from another modal, without closing the first one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, material-design

I find some solution, but none of them are legit to my code.

So, basically I'm trying to open a modal to confirm that the user really want to cancel and quit the process. The second modal will open, but the first one will close. 
The flow is this. If the user cancel, another pop-up will open and ask the user if he want to quit. If the user click on Yes, the process end, and everything will work corectly. 
But, if the user click on No, I want the first modal to be shown again.

Maybe the code will help you.

**html**

```
<md-dialog flex="40" aria-label="Edit Light">

    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>Manual select bridge</h2>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

   <md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="editBridge" name="editBridge">
            <!--Bridge-->

              <!--Bridge-->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="light-bridge-select" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bridge</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 pr30">
                        <select id="light-bridge-select" class="form-control" ng-model="light.bridgeMac" data-required-cond="{{ light.commissioned }}"
                            ng-options="item.mac as item.name for item in bridgesList">
                            <option value="" disabled >Select Bridge</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <div style="height:15px" class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--ID-->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Light ID</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div flex>
                            <input name="light-id" data-light-id class="form-control" ng-model="light.newidentifier" type="number">
                            <info-tooltip key="light.form.light_id"></info-tooltip>
                            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:15px" class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>


                <div ng-show="showError" style="height:15px" class="help-block with-errors">
                    <p class="text-danger"> All fields are required.</p>
                </div>
                  <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
                        <span flex></span>
                        <md-button ng-click="save()">Save</md-button>
                        <md-button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
                  </md-dialog-actions>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

```
.js file

this.manualMapping= function (bridges,light) {

    return $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: "views/common/modals/manual-mapping-light.html",
        resolve: {
            bridges: function () {
                return bridges
            },
            light: function () {
                return light
            }
        },
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        skipHide:true,
       controller: [
            '$rootScope',
            '$scope',
            'defaults.services',
            'modal.services',
            'profile.services',
            '$timeout',
            function (
                $rootScope,
                $scope,
                $defaultServices,
                $modalServices,
                $profileServices,
                $timeout
            ) {
             $timeout(function () {
                    var addLightForm = $('#addLight');

                    addLightForm.validator({
                        disable: false,
                        focus: true,
                        excluded: [':disabled'],
                        feedback: {
                            success: 'glyphicon-ok',
                            error: 'glyphicon-remove'
                        },
                        custom: {

                             'light-id': function () {
                                return $profileServices.checkLightDuplicateId(
                                    $scope.light.customLightId,
                                    $scope.light.identifier
                                ) ? 'Duplicate Light Id' : undefined
                            },
                        }
                    });
             });
             $scope.bridgesList = bridges

             $scope.save = function(){

                $profileServices.manualUpdateBridgeOrDelete(light.identifier, $scope.light.bridgeMac, $scope.light.newidentifier, light.room,true).
                then(function (response) {

                if(response){
                     $modalServices.modalAlert('The light you added was commissioned','Light succesfully added!').then(function(){
                         $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshProfile');
                     })

                }
                else{
                    $modalServices.modalAlert("The light you added wasn't commissioned",'Error','red').then(function(){
                         $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshProfile');
                     })

                }

                })

             }

             $scope.cancel = function() {
             var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
              .title('Are you sure you want to cancel?')
              .textContent('If you cancel the commissioning process of the light you added, it will remove the light! Are you sure you want to cancel?')
              .ok('Yes')
              .cancel('No');

               $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
                $modalServices.modalAlert("The light was added, but not commissioned!",'Succes','red').then(function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshProfile');
               },
               function(){

               });

             });

        }
        }]
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t do it. Nested dialogs and modals are bad UX. Rethink the user flow.

Comment: @Timir, well Google uses it) But for sure you know better...

Comment: Lol. I just think Google needs to divert some budget toward hiring better UX people

Comment: well, when the client wants something, you have to do it. I could do that by setting the multiple value to true. $mdDialog.show(confirm.multiple(true)).then(function() ...